# Drupal 6 form refresh issue

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I made a simple drupal form that upon submit states that the page has been submitted. The data is put into a database. If the page is refreshed after the submit, data is re-entered, even though the user did not press submit again, they simply had refreshed the page. Why is a refresh re-running the submit function? How can this be prevented?  A redirect is one option, is there any other?

Comment: strange... Drupal does a 302 to the same page to prevent the resubmission.

Comment: can you post some code with the form, validation and submit functions?